# Haskell - expected type vs. actual type

Tags: haskell, types

I've defined the following function:

```
calculateApproximation :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Double -> Double
calculateApproximation n a r tol =
  if abs(((take n xs)!!(n-1)) - (((take n xs)!!(n-2)))) <= tol
    then ((take n xs)!!(n-1))
    else calculateApproximation (n+1) a r tol
  where xs = unfoldr (\x -> Just(x, (x + (r/x))/2)) a
```

But I'm seeing the following type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Double'
    In the second argument of `(<=)', namely `tol'
    In the expression:
      abs (((take n xs) !! (n - 1)) - (((take n xs) !! (n - 2)))) <= tol
```

But then, why is it expecting `tol` to be an Int, when I've already defined it as Double? Or is there a totally silly mistake I'm overlooking here?

Comment: What is the `calculateApproximation` function supposed to do?

Comment: What is the type of `xs`? Since `r` is an `Int`, `r/x` doesn't make sense. Do you mean `(fromIntegral r)/x`?

Comment: It should extract elements from an infinite list representing a convergent sequence, until the difference between two successive terms is smaller than a given margin. And yeah, the type of xs was being inferred as `[Int]`, I actually needed to define `r` and `a` as Doubles...

Comment: Use `fromIntegral r` and `fromIntegral a` to get `Double`s from `Int`s.

Comment: Also you can use the `!!` operator directly on infinite lists. No need to `take` it first. So you could write your `if` condition as `abs (xs !! (n - 1) - xs !! (n - 2))` and your `then` branch as `xs !! (n - 1)`.

Comment: That code is bad in several ways (unrelated to the error): There's no need to use `take` before `!!`, there are several repeated subexpressions, the code uses `!!`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest fix is to modify the type signature so that your initial guess `a` and the number you are computing the square root of, `r`, are `Double` rather than `Int`.

I've also taken the liberty of factoring out the definition `ys = take n xs` to simplify the code a little.

```
calculateApproximation :: Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
calculateApproximation n a r tol =
    if abs (ys!!(n-1) - ys!!(n-2)) <= tol
      then ys!!(n-1)
      else calculateApproximation (n+1) a r tol
    where xs = unfoldr (\x -> Just(x, (x + (r/x))/2)) a
          ys = take n xs
```

However, as was pointed out in the comments, you don't actually need to take `n` elements before looking up the `n-1`th element. You can apply `!!` to infinite lists, which simplifies your code further to

```
calculateApproximation :: Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
calculateApproximation n a r tol =
    if abs (xs!!(n-1) - xs!!(n-2)) <= tol
        then xs!!(n-1)
        else calculateApproximation (n+1) a r tol
    where xs = unfoldr (\x -> Just(x, (x + (r/x))/2)) a
```

I would probably factor out a few more definitions for clarity, giving

```
calculateApproximation' n a r tol = go n
  where
    go n = let eps = abs $ xs!!(n-1) - xs!!(n-2)
            in if eps <= tol
                then xs !! (n-1)
                else go (n+1)

    xs = unfoldr (\x -> Just (x, (x + r/x)/2)) a
```

Finally, I would notice that the operation `go` only ever uses the `n-1` and `n-2` elements of the list, never the earlier elements, and that the index `n` is only used to keep track of where you are in the list. So I would rewrite so that `go` operates on the list, rather than on the index, and have it iterate through the list until it finds a suitable answer. And in one minor tidy-up, I'd change from `unfoldr` to `iterate` -- you only really want `unfoldr` if the list is supposed to terminate at some point.

```
calculateApproximation a r tol = go xs
  where
    go (x:y:rest) = if abs (x-y) < tol
        then y
        else go (y:rest)

    xs = iterate (\x -> (x+r/x)/2) a
```

Answer (score 4):

"Actual" refers to `tol` being given the type of `Double` in the signature of `calculate`.

"Expected" refers to `tol` having to be an `Int` to make sense on the right hand side of a `<=` where the left hand side is already an `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `xs` to have type `Double`, the type of the anonymous function in the `unfoldr` must be `a -> Just (a, Double)`. If the second part of the pair is to involve a sum like the one in your definition, you probably want `a` to be `Double` as well. Finally, `r/x` does not make sense since `r :: Int`, so you want

```
xs = unfoldr (\x -> Just(x, (x + ((fromIntegral r)/x))/2)) (fromIntegral a).
```

(I feel there are surely shorter/clearer ways of writing this. You might want to think about that - or look at Chris Taylor's answer.)

PS: See also Aadit M Shah's comments about getting rid of the `take`s.

Comment: See Tom Ellis' answer if you wonder why `xs` not having type `[Double]` causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write your code:

```
import Data.List

calculateApproximation :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Int -> Double
calculateApproximation a r tol = getApproximation
    where xs = unfoldr (\x -> Just (x, (x + r / x) / 2)) a
          getApproximation n = if abs (x - xs !! (n - 2)) <= tol
                                   then x else getApproximation (n + 1)
              where x = xs !! (n - 2)
```

What solves the problem is changing the types of `a` and `r` from `Int` to `Double`.